# Combine data from multiple SSAS cubes in PowerBI

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I need to combine data from multiple SSAS cubes and visualize in one dashboard. It seems only one SSAS cube can be added to Power BI desktop, there is an option to import data as a flat table but in this case cube structure would be falt and useless.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, only one cube can be accessed at design time using the live connection.

2 ways to solve your problem:
1 - build a new cube, accessing all the data that you need
2 - switch to import mode and build your own model

good luck!